# How to reset only year in input type date field?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to reset only year in date input base in some condition.

See below example where I want to reset year if user type date greater than `2022-12-31`.

When I tried it resets whole date but I just want to reset year not full date.

**Example:** if user type `01/01/2023` then it should be reset as `01/01/yyyy`.

```js
$('#date-input').change(function(e) {
  let input = $(this);
  
  if (input.prop('max') < input.val()) {
    var value = input.val().substring(5, 10);
    console.log(value);
    input.val(value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="date-input" placeholder="MM / DD / YY" max="2022-12-31"></span>
```

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(value);`?

Comment: @PrathapReddy if you select date `01/01/2023` then output will be `01-01`. you can check by your self too by providing date greater than 01/01/2020.

Comment: Pardon me, mobile `chrome` browser is not allowing to type. Showing only `date picker` and it showing till the max date . So if you update `input.val(value);`, it's updating it as just `01-01`. Have you tried adding year to it by `new Date().getFullYear() + '-' value` while setting `input.val(...)`?

Comment: @PrathapReddy yes I have tried `input.val(new Date().getFullYear() + '-' + value);` and it's working. But don't want to set any year. I want to just clear out year.

Comment: Gocha. You only need to preserve the date and month. Year field should be cleared or should set to `yyyy`. I am not sure you can achieve that with built in input `type='date'`. Agreeing with @FluffyKitten answer. (Or) You can write custom input with `type: text` and date picker `icon` combination separately where you can get full control on input value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, I'm afraid. When you set the date for the input, it must be a valid date.

The best you can do is set it to a date and then display a message to warn the user they
have entered a date later than the max date. You could set it to the current year, or a year that makes no sense if don't want people mistakenly continuing with the current year (e.g. even "0001" will work), but you cannot clear just the year to `yyyy`.

In the example below, if the date is after the max date:

- Get the entered year and display a message to say it is invalid
- Replaces the entered year with the current year
- Puts focus back on the input - it is not possible to set focus on the year specifically, but in most cases it will select the year as the last entered info when the whole input gets focus.

```js
$('#date-input').change(function(e) {
  let input = $(this);
  
    $('.date-error').text("");

if (input.prop('max') < input.val()) {
    var inputyear = input.val().substring(0, 4);
    $('.date-error').text(inputyear+ " is not a valid year. Please enter a date before 31/12/2022");

    var value = input.val().substring(5, 10);
    CurrYear = new Date().getFullYear();
    value = CurrYear+"-"+value;
    input.val(value);

    input.focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="date-input" placeholder="MM / DD / YY" max="2022-12-31"></span>
<div class="date-error"></div>
```