# asp.NET TextBox with DateMode How to set focus on Year field?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I have hundreds of asp:TextBox's with Date mode. Due to massive data entry, our users prefer entering the date value manually, and they may enter a wrong value by mistake, e.g. "12/02/2122" instead of "12/02/2022". In that case, I force them to fix this error by setting focus on itself so that they cannot move to the next control. However, "focus()" always highlights the month field, like this:
[image]

But I really want to highlight the year field instead. Is it possible with javascript?

Just in case, here is a short code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="dteAccident" ClientInstanceName="dteAccident" runat="server" onblur="jsDateAutoFixEx(this);" TextMode="Date" />

function jsDateAutoFixEx(Sender) {
    var oValue = Sender.value;  // yyyy-MM-dd
    yearfield = oValue.split("-")[0];
    year2digitFront = yearfield.slice(0, 2);
    if (year2digitFront != "19" && year2digitFront != "20") {
        Sender.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it isn't possible: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63566199/how-to-reset-only-year-in-input-type-date-field